# Authorization denied because request would have exceeded max copies fo the following authorization number

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-license-manager

My system crashed , so I had to reinstall the OS and then I had to re-install ArcGIS Desktop.

But , while trying to reinstall ArcGIS Desktop, it is failing in the authorization step when I give my old Authorization Code, earlier obtained from my Esri account.

I am getting the below error on the final step of authorizing ArcGIS Desktop.

> Authorization denied because request would have exceeded max copies fo
> the following authorization number(s) :xxxxxxxxxxxx

How do I authorize ArcGIS Desktop again using my Authorization Code which is valid until Feb 2017?

Answer (score 2):

License queries need to go through to whoever issued your license.  This would normally be Esri or one of their distributors.

Contact details for Esri and their distributors can be found on the [Esri Contact Us page](http://www.esri.com/about-esri/contact).